# Engine hot 2007 Chevy impala ls

Tags: chevrolet, impala

This morning when I went into work my engine & everything on my dash was working & reading normal, I just got out of work & now my dash reads “engine hot/ac off” & the temperature gauge is stuck all the down at cold. It’s a 15 min drive home from work & I’ve now been parked & had the car off for over an hour & a half & I didn’t start it but just turned it on & it is still reading that the engine is hot. Help??

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

You may have an issue with a faulty temperature sensor or wiring. Your engine is clearly not hot if it has been sitting for hours. Your owner's manual contains the following passage, which indicates that it should be safe to drive home, but if the message persists you need to have a mechanic check the car.

[image]